# Is there any way to display the best bgp route in Quagga?

Tags: bgp, quagga

Does anyone know if there's an equivalent of sh ip bgp X.X.X.X bestpath (from Cisco) in Quagga? I cannot find it in the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like does not have such command.

**"show ip bgp", "show ip bgp neighbors 10.0.0.2 advertised-routes"**
able to find ">" for bestpath.

or follow command is work.

```
vtysh -c 'show ip bgp' | grep -i '>'
```

You must run on you OS shell.
its better than 'show ip bgp regex'

Answer (score 0):

Try `show ip bgp ipv4 unicast`

Example:

```
# show ip bgp ipv4 unicast 8.8.8.8
BGP routing table entry for 8.8.8.0/24
Paths: (1 available, best #1, table Default-IP-Routing-Table)
  Not advertised to any peer
  64515 65534 20473 15169
    169.254.169.254 from 169.254.169.254 (144.202.118.91)
      Origin IGP, localpref 100, valid, external, best
      Community: 64515:44
      Last update: Mon Apr  9 06:33:18 2018
```